# want to display the values according to cell name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

here am facing an issue that in my original file i want to display values from another sheet according to cell name ( not by cell reference) for if the table "code" is in column A then display the names under "code" in the next sheet, display the same if i change "code" from column A to column C or wherever. pls help me to display values according to cell name.

here is the sample sheet.. pls take a look
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xAUmvmaZPvfJwCHD_esrshLccgKM3VmP1CI46mMoRB8/edit#gid=1437285308

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed it in the sheet directly with the formula:

```
=QUERY('Sheet A'!A2:Z,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("code",'Sheet A'!A1:Z1,0),4),1,""))
```